# How to react to clicking NOT on the line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, interactive

I have a dense Matlab plot with many curves, and I want the user to be able to highlight one of the lines (in addition to just seeing a datatip on it). It works fine, however I cannot find a way to "unselect" all lines: I cannot find an action to which to assign the "unselect" function. I tried it with adding a dedicated text and assigning to its `ButtonDownFcn` but it doesn't seem to be called. Ideally, I'd like the "unselect" function to be called when just clicking empty space (not on any curve), but the workaround with the extra text would also work.

The MWE:

```
clear
close all
p(1) = plot(0:100, sin(0:100));
hold on
p(2) = plot(0:100, cos(0:100));
legend('sin', 'cos')
ylim([-2, 2])

% Attach a method to clicking a plot line
datacursormode on;
dcmgr = datacursormode(gcf);
set(dcmgr, 'UpdateFcn', @select)


function output_txt = select(~, event_obj, ~)
% change tooltip
pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
output_txt = {...
    [event_obj.Target.DisplayName]...
    num2str(pos(1), 4)...
    num2str(pos(2), 4) ...
};

% reset line widths, make them semi-transparent
p = findall(gcf, 'type', 'line');
set(p, 'LineWidth', 1);
for i = 1:numel(p)
    p(i).Color = [p(i).Color, 0.2];
end

% set selected line width to 2 and colour to fully opaque
event_obj.Target.LineWidth = 2;
event_obj.Target.Color = [event_obj.Target.Color, 1];

% create a "clear selection" object --> THIS PART DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK
t = text(0, 0, 'clear');
set(t, 'ButtonDownFcn', @unselect)
end

function unselect
p = findall(gcf, 'type', 'line');
set(p, 'LineWidth', 1);
for i = 1:numel(p)
    p(i).Color = [p(i).Color, 1];
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that Matlab overrides the `ButtonDownFcn` listener when `datacursormode` is enabled (zoom, pan and rotate3d as well). If you turn off `datacursormode` the `ButtonDownFcn` will work.

More info on this behavior here: [Matlab Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51680-datacursormode-overwrites-keypressfcn-by-setting-in-protective-listeners-how-can-i-automatically-s)

I could not get the button down function to work, but the following code works on R2019a using a key press as the event. I used the `c` key, but you can use whatever maes the most sense for your case.

```matlab
clear
close all
F = figure();
hManager = uigetmodemanager(F);
p(1) = plot(0:100, sin(0:100));
hold on
p(2) = plot(0:100, cos(0:100));
legend('sin', 'cos')
ylim([-2, 2])

% Attach a method to clicking a plot line
dcmgr = datacursormode(gcf);
datacursormode on;
hManager.WindowListenerHandles(1).Enabled = false;
hManager.WindowListenerHandles(2).Enabled = false;
set(dcmgr, 'UpdateFcn', @select)
set(F, 'KeyPressFcn', @unselect)

function output_txt = select(~, event_obj, ~)

% change tooltip
pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
output_txt = {...
    [event_obj.Target.DisplayName]...
    num2str(pos(1), 4)...
    num2str(pos(2), 4) ...
};

% reset line widths, make them semi-transparent
p = findall(gcf, 'type', 'line');
set(p, 'LineWidth', 1);
for i = 1:numel(p)
    p(i).Color = [p(i).Color, 0.2];
end

% set selected line width to 2 and colour to fully opaque
event_obj.Target.LineWidth = 2;
event_obj.Target.Color = [event_obj.Target.Color, 1];

end


function unselect(fig, event_obj)

if strcmpi(class(event_obj),'matlab.ui.eventdata.KeyData') && ...
        ~isempty(event_obj.Character) && ...
        event_obj.Character == 'c'
    
    p = findall(gcf, 'type', 'line');
    set(p, 'LineWidth', 1);
    for i = 1:numel(p)
        p(i).Color = [p(i).Color, 1];
    end
    
    % Delete data tips
    figObjs = findall(fig);
    pdth = figObjs(arrayfun(@(h)isa(h,'matlab.graphics.shape.internal.PointDataTip'),figObjs));
    for idx = 1:numel(pdth)
        delete(pdth(idx))
    end
end

end
```